# How to change the "select lasso" become original setting , now the "select lasso" is irregular

Tags: modeling, objects, interface, selection-tools

[image]

Could you mind teach me, how to change the "select lasso" key become original setting, because now I have the problem that I can't control the shape in "vertex selection mode" , and the other problem is that I can't use the "shift" key to choose the vertices (the orange point in the screenshot).
Could you mind teach me to solve the problem Your are my superhero ! Thank You !

Comment: maybe use the "3" key this time, in order to be in face selection mode..

Comment: ❤️❤️❤️you saved my life again !!!!!my superhero!!!!!!

Comment: Pressing 'W' toggles between box, lasso and circle select modes. you'll see that the icon changes each time you change modes.

Comment: Eureka!!!!!!Thank you for your teaching and guidance!!!❤️❤️❤️